# VueJS 2 Templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new VueJS Student!

I made a "**MainTemplate.vue**", there are a menu, footer, header...
So a create another .vue named "**ComponentB.vue**".

Here is my code **ComponentB.vue**

```
<template>  
    <h1>Component B</h1>
</template>
```

So simple. I imported this to my "**MainTemplate.vue**" and it worked well.
But i don't know why if this template "**ComponentB.vue**" has a lot of code, it will not work.

Look, i simple add more code to my "**ComponenteB.vue**"

```
<template>  
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
</template>
```

When i save, the browser get to me this **error**:

```
client?cd17:139 ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-4e4e09bc","hasScoped":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/ComponenteB.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 
  Error compiling template:

  <h1>Component B</h1>
  <h1>Component B</h1>
  <h1>Component B</h1>
  <h1>Component B</h1>
  <h1>Component B</h1>
  <h1>Component B</h1>

Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

 @ ./src/ComponenteB.vue 6:2-198
 @ ./src/routes.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Why i can't put more code inside ? Anyone can help me please?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right there in the error message:

> Component template should contain exactly one root element

Wrap the contents of your `ComponentB.vue` template in a div, so that it has one root element:

```
<template>  
  <div>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
    <h1>Component B</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```